# Dynamically find minimum value in cumulative total for a horizontal array

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, cumulative-sum

I have a range of horizontal data:

|  | A | B | C | D | E | F | G | H | I |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Sum | Available | Export | Export | Import | Sum | Available | Export | Export |  |
| 2 | 20 | >9< | -2 | -4 | 10 | 24 | >14< | -10 | -5 | ... |

After every "Sum" column (e.g. B2) I want to calculate a running total for the data in the columns to the right, that have the headers "Import" or "Export" (And not "Sum","Available" or empty columns), but using the "Sum" to the left as the initial value. I expect this result, that I can then wrap the MIN function around.

=MIN(20;18;14;24;14;9)

As I need this calculation to be dynamic and I cannot use helper rows, I tried two ways using the ARRAYFORMULA() in Google Sheets.

1. MIN of ARRAYFORMULA with SUMIF:

```
MIN(ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF(LEN(C2:2),
    (SUMIF(COLUMN(C2:2),"<="&COLUMN(C2:2),C2:2))
  ,"")
))
```

This gives me a working column-wise running total, but I cannot filter out the values for the columns named "Sum". And SUMIFS apparently does not work in the array formula. Also I cannot find a way to add A2 as the initial value.

2. MIN of ARRAYFORMULA with MMULT

```
MIN(ARRAYFORMULA(
  IF(TRANSPOSE(C1:1)=1,
    MMULT(
      TRANSPOSE(N(COLUMN(C2:2)>=TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(C2:2)))*N(N78:Y78=TRANSPOSE(C2:2))),
      TRANSPOSE(N(C2:2))
    )
  ,"")
))
```

For this to work, I had to use a helper column that translates "Import" and "Export" columns to "1". This matrix multiplication usually uses data stored in rows and not columns, which is why I had to transpose the data around until I got this as a result:

MIN(-2;-6;4; ;-6;-11; )

This feels like progress, even though, I am still missing the initial value in A2. I cannot find a way to also include this one value in the calculation.

How do I get the correct value (9) to be displayed in field B2? Any ideas or comments are highly appreciated.

Comment: I have to say, I read and work on complex "stuff" daily; and after three readings, I still don't understand the goal. Actually, you lost me at "After every 'Sum' column (e.g. B2) I want to calculate..." You've shown us one partial row of data. In that tiny sample, I see three "Sum" columns: A, E, H. So (e.g., B2) would mean you want calculations to be in B2, F2 and I2. But you already show data in the latter two of those three cells, while B2 is blank. From there it only goes further downhill for me.

Comment: I suggest that you share a link to a sample spreadsheet with several rows of realistic data. Indicate where a formula should go and *hand-enter* the results you expect that formula to produce for those rows. Somewhere in empty columns nearby, explain the logic behind those results individually (even if just for three rows).

Comment: Actually, after looking at this longer, your image shows TWO instances of Col D, which you'll want to fix, as that contributes to the confusion.

Comment: Hi Erik, thanks for your comments. I updated my question to be more accurate and created this Sheet with some more realistic data: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/192sgmbtJ38OR4g8D9bW7o8RpiAzpVMCTZszM-5aX72A/edit#gid=0

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(MIN(MMULT(IFNA((COLUMN(B2:2)<=TRANSPOSE(COLUMN(B2:2)))*
 FILTER(B2:2, REGEXMATCH(B1:1, "Import|Export")), 0),
 SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(B2:2), 1, 1, ))))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi player0, thanks for your answer, I will need a formula in B2 and G2 , that takes the "Sum" column to their left (A2 and F2) as the initial value for the running total of "Import|Export" columns to the right..